# Is it possible to schedule an anacron single line command execution instead of sourcing a file?

Tags: linux, scheduling, syntax, anacron

Everywhere on the internet, in articles or tutorials (in the searching of "schedule an anacron command"), I find a format such as the following:

```
@daily    15    rsync.daily   /bin/bash /home/steven/script/backuprsync.sh
```

Then I'm wondering if it is possible to schedule a single (line) command (instead of sourcing an entire file) and which would be the correct syntax form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/bin/bash /home/steven/script/backuprsync.sh
```

This is a single command.  It runs a script.

You can enter any single command in the `anacrontab` command field.

For example:

```
@weekly    0    my-weekly-rm    rm /tmp/delete-me
```

It is however much more common to schedule scripts as they would allow for doing more complicated things.